# Extract rows based on keys

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
key1 key2 col3 col4 col5 value
A    B    C    D    F    good1
F    C    C    D    F    adsf
A    D    C    D    F    good2
N    B    C    D    F    afd
A    B    C    D    F    dsf
A    D    C    D    F    fads
```

I am trying to extract the values from key1, and key2 columns where value includes "good". Using Then I would like to extract all the rows from the table that include those keys.

The expected result is:

```
key1 key2 col3 col4 col5 value
A    B    C    D    F    good1
A    D    C    D    F    good2
A    B    C    D    F    dsf
A    D    C    D    F    fads
```

So far, I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT key1, key2
FROM my_table tb1
WHERE tb1.value LIKE '%good%'
```

with python pandas, I'd store the result of above and extract all the columns from `my_table`. Is there a way to do this efficiently in SQL without having to create a second table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists` for this:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where exists (select 1
              from my_table t2
              where t2.value like '%good%' and
                    t2.key1 = t.key1 and
                    t2.key2 = t.key2 
             );
```